# Error: data and salt arguments required (Async)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

I have a problem with Schema.pre('save'), in my model 'user', cannot get 'this' for the hashed of my password with bcrypt.

my app.js, Simple connect in mongodb using mongoose

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/gederson', {
  useMongoClient: true,

});

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected on mongo');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log('listening');
});

index(app, db);
post(app, db);
admin(app, db);


module.exports = app;
```

my route, I created the route for create user in my application, but in pre 'save' cannot get the 'this' for hash password.

```
const Users = db.model('Users');

const newUser = {
          username: req.body.username,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: req.body.password,
        };
        Users.create(newUser, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.status = 201;
          return res.send('User created');
        });
```

my model user, the code pre 'save'

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

UserSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
  const user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    user.password = hash;
    return next();
  });
});

const Users = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);

module.exports = Users;
```

Stack Error:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: data and salt arguments required
    at /home/gedersonchiquesi/ProjetosDev/wos/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:114:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue today.

I resolved the matter by removing the ES6 syntax (arrow function).

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
     if (err) {
     return next(err);
     }
     user.password = hash;
     next();
  })
});
```

Comment: Yeah, in the same day i resolved this pre('save'), arrow functions do not accept the 'this'

Answer (score 1):

because you are passing the blank value of the inputs  on that function

if test on postman or else data input needed
[image]

```
{
    "name":"test",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "password":"123456"
}
```

add see my code example for  datastore

```
router.post("/register-user", (req, res, next) => {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10).then((hash) => {
        const user = new userSchema({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hash
        });
        user.save().then((response) => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "User successfully created!",
                result: response
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: error
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was my server wasn't accepting the correct data type.
Had to include the following on server.js file:
`app.use(express.json());` &
`app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));`